# bluealsa: Couldn't acquire D-Bus name: org.bluealsa

Tags: raspbian, audio, bluetooth, alsa

Trying to use my Raspberry Pi 4 as an A2DP Bluetooth sink using `bluealsa`.
As reading the [documentation](https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa#configuration--usage) of `bluealsa`:

> It will register `org.bluealsa` service in the D-Bus system bus, which can be used for accessing configured audio devices.

But when I run:

```
$ bluealsa
```

it gives me this exception:

```
bluealsa: Couldn't acquire D-Bus name: org.bluealsa
```

So where is the problem and if it's significant one how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

**Section 3** at the bottom of the installation guide [Troubleshooting part](https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa#troubleshooting):

> 3. Couldn't acquire D-Bus name: org.bluealsa
>
> It is not possible to run more than one instance of the BlueALSA
>   server per D-Bus interface. If one tries to run second instance, it
>   will fail with the "Couldn't acquire D-Bus name: org.bluealsa" error
>   message. This message might also appear when D-Bus policy does not
>   allow acquiring "org.bluealsa" name for a particular user - by default
>   only root is allowed to start BlueALSA server.

---

> It is not possible to run more than one instance...

- `sudo killall bluealsa`
- `sudo bluealsa`

> This message might also appear when D-Bus policy does not
>   allow acquiring...

- `sudo nano /etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf`

> By default
>   only root is allowed to start BlueALSA server...

- `sudo bluealsa`

Answer (score 0):

for whom it may concern, i was directed here beause my bluetooth headset could not switch to high fidelity mode from my window-manager via blueman-applet and in the process i figured out i have to be in the messagebus group. so sudo usermod -a -G messagebus $username

edit: given i'm an idiot, it's probably more "usermod -aG bluetooth pulse"

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/134495)

Comment: please delete this non-answer